# how to use graphQL parent parameters

Tags: reactjs

I have created LogEvents field in the root query
by the way I am not sure how to use parent's parameters in the child fileds
Please make sure this. Best

```
const RootQuery = new GraphQLObjectType({
name: 'RootQueryType',
fields: {       
    LogEvents: {
        type: new GraphQLList(LogEvent),
        args: { DeviceID: { type: GraphQLInt } },
        resolve(parent, args) {
            return getEventListByDeviceID(args.DeviceID)
        }
    }
}
```

})

Comment: Hi Teodor, What is the issue and would you check out the [formatting guide](https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help) to update the question?

Answer (score 0):

in the "LogEvents" field, you used LogEvent type.
so for example in your LogEvent type you can use parent's parameters
Something like that

```
const EventAttribute = new GraphQLObjectType({
  /////custome your type
})

const LogEvent = new GraphQLObjectType({
    name: 'LogEvent',
    fields: {      
        EventAttribute: {
            type: EventAttribute,
            resolve(parent, args) {
                return getEventAttributesByEventID(parent.EventID)
            }

        }
    }
})
```

Answer (score 0):

that is well working

```
const LogEvent = new GraphQLObjectType({
    name: 'LogEvent',
    fields: {      
        EventAttribute: {
            type: EventAttribute,
            resolve(parent, args) {
                return getEventAttributesByEventID(parent.EventID)
            }

        }
    }
})

const RootQuery = new GraphQLObjectType({
 name: 'RootQueryType',
 fields: {       
     LogEvents: {
         type: new GraphQLList(LogEvent),
         args: { DeviceID: { type: GraphQLInt } },
         resolve(parent, args) {
             return getEventListByDeviceID(args.DeviceID)
         }
     }
 }
 })
```